# Issues in estimation and plot

Tags: estimation, matlab, regression-coefficients

I am learning adaptive filters and testing the performance of using Least Squares and Kalman filter for parameter estimation for $y = X + \text{noise}$. The model is autoregressive AR(2) model
 $$y(t) = ay_{t-1} + by_{t-2}$$
and a Moving Average MA(2) model. I have obtained the parameters $(\hat{a},\hat{b})$ for AR and MA.  I want to show the plot of the desired signal vs the actual signal so that it shows how close the estimated signal is from the actual. How do I recover the signal and show the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not looking to forecast anything, given a signal $Y$ and the following code will give you a plot of the inferred versus the actual series' residuals from an AR(2) model:

```
mdl = arima(2,0,0); % Simple ARIMA(2,0,0) 
rng(123)            % Set the random seed

Y = sin(linspace(0,20,52))' + randn(52,1);    % Some junk data'


EstMdl = estimate(mdl,Y);                     % Estimate your model
[E,V] = infer(EstMdl,Y(3:end),'Y0',Y(1:2));   % Infer model residuals using 
                                              % the first two values as presample
plot(Y(3:end)); hold on;                       
plot(E,'r'); hold off                          
legend('Original Stuff', 'My stuff')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will this method apply when I apply other estimation techniques like Maximum likelihood or Kalman filter for estimating the state and parameters?The thing is once I estimated the parameters & state, I wanted to get the same plot as you have done.But I am unsure if estimate() and infer() command will be applicable. My concern is how do I pass the estimated coefficients into infer() since I am not using estimate() function.

Comment: Shouldn't deconvolution give the desired signal?

Comment: You can omit the call `estimate` if you specify your model's coefficients directly. You will probably need syntax like: `mdl = arima('AR',{ param1, param2}, ...`. Then you can pass the object `mdl` to `infer` once more.

Comment: @ quick questions (1) In many cases I have seen models with the functional form y(t)=1 + 0.2y(t-1) + 0.6y(t-3), is the 1 an intercept? How do I specify the "1" or "0.5" intercept in mdl = arima() (2) When calculating Means Square error between the actual (h) coefficients and the desired(H), do we consider the estimated  intercept in the formula for MSE?Ex in the Eq in (1), will mse = sum((H-h).^2)/4 OR mse = sum((H-h).^2)/3

Comment: (1) I believe you want to use `Constant`. (2) I haven't seen MSE being used to compare estimated and true coefficients, only estimated and true sample values; maybe I am wrong... In any case if you have 3 coefficient that you estimate why would you divide by 4? :D Finally check the functionality of `lagmatrix` in conjunction with `fitlm`, it will allow you to get OLS estimates for what you describe.